# Custom template for array field in Meteor autoform

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

If I have a simple schema:

```
Schemas.User = new SimpleSchema({
  emails: {
    type: [Object],
    optional: true
  },
  "emails.$.address": {
    type: String,
    regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
  },
  "emails.$.verified": {
    type: Boolean
  },
  "emails.$.description": {
    type: String
  },
  "emails.$.provider": {
    type: String
  },

  ...

});
```

If I use `autoform` to print a form, I can use

```
{{> afQuickField name="emails"}}
```

to print a box in which I can add new or remove/update existing emails to the user. I like the option to add/remove objects but the design is quite ugly. I want the rows in a table instead, so I have to replace the template with a custom template.

How can I do this? I guess this is the template currently being used https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/devel/templates/bootstrap3/components/afArrayField/afArrayField.html but instead of having each object in the array as a list group item, I need them to be table rows with each field in each column.

How should the template be customized and how can I swap the templates used?